# can't complete the installation of gitolite

Tags: git, github, gitolite

I have installed Git and now I am trying to install `gitolite` on my server , so I typed:

```
git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
gitolite/install
```

the result of this command is as follow

```
use the following full path for gitolite: /root/gitolite/src/gitolite
```

how i can complete the installation

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [the file you are trying to execute](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/install), there are some helpful comments:

```
Usage (from gitolite clone directory):

    ./install
    to run gitolite using an absolute or relative path, for example
    'src/gitolite' or '/full/path/to/this/dir/src/gitolite'

    ./install -ln [<dir>]
    to symlink just the gitolite executable to some <dir> that is in
    $PATH. <dir> defaults to $HOME/bin if <dir> not specified. <dir> is
    assumed to exist; gitolite will not create it.

    Please provide a full path, not a relative path.

    ./install -to <dir>
    to copy the entire 'src' directory to <dir>. If <dir> is not in
    $PATH, use the full path to run gitolite commands.

    Please provide a full path, not a relative path.

Simplest use, if $HOME/bin exists and is in $PATH, is:

    git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
    gitolite/install -ln

    # now run setup
    gitolite setup -pk /path/to/YourName.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is considered "completed installation" now. To use it you have to use the path it outputs.

If you want to install it on path, you must use the form:

```
./install --to <dir>
```

Recommended is:

```
./install --to $HOME/bin
```